# Skipping header when reading CSV

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv

I want to be able to skip the header when reading and writing to csv

Here is the code I have so far

```
  try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writefilename))// StreamWriter is used to write a text file
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readfilename)) // StreamReader is used to read a text file
            {
                //Writing headings to file
                heading = "NI Number,Surname,Forename,Employee,Employer(gross),Contribution Status,Contribution Status Date";
                sw.WriteLine(heading);


                while ((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  // Reads one line into the variable txtline
                {



                    //spiliting the file into columns if there is something in it.
                    //oldcolumns = txtline.Split(',');

                    oldcolumns = Regex.Split(txtline, ",");

                    //spliting old columns[0] where there is a space and putting it in the names array.
                    //names = Regex.Split(oldcolumns[0],",");
                  string []  names = oldcolumns[0].Split(' ');
                  var result = string.Join(" ", oldcolumns[0].Split(' ').Skip(1));




                    //writing the oldcolumns data into the newcolumns.
                    newcolumns[0] = oldcolumns[1];
                    newcolumns[1] = result;
                    newcolumns[2] = names[0];
                    newcolumns[3] = oldcolumns[9];
                    newcolumns[4] = oldcolumns[11];
                    newcolumns[5] = "";
                    newcolumns[6] = "";


                    //using loop to run through all the columns
                    csvline = "";


                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                    {
                        csvline = csvline + "\"" + newcolumns[i].Replace("\"", "") + "\",";
                    }

                    //writing to file.
                    sw.WriteLine(csvline);
                }
```

I understand that if I wanted to skip a column I could do this in the for loop but I dont know how to skip a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is discard the first line of a file, simply call `ReadLine()` and discard the result before further processing:

```
// Discard the header row
sr.ReadLine()

// Do further processing
while ((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```

Please note that one line does not necessarily mean one row in CSV. Use a library to read CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the rows & ignore it:

```
for ( int LineNo = 1; ; LineNo++)
{
  ReadLine
  if (LineNo == 1)
    continue
}
```

(pseudo-code before anyone comments :-) )

Comment: Please try to suggest code that OP can actually incorporate in their code. For your code to work, one first needs to read the entire file in order to count the number of lines in it (and one line doesn't have to mean one row in CSV). OP is using a `while()` loop.

Comment: I cant see the difference between my pseudocode & what you said in words - it calls readline & discards the first line. It also has the same problem that you commented that it will fail on multiline content. I trust the OP is competent enough to convert a for loop into a while loop.

Comment: In order to make your `for()` loop work, you need to know how many lines there are (`for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)`). For that reason you need to read the entire file in memory at once. You don't want that. You also don't need to `ReadLine()` _inside_ the loop at all, it's always the first line(s), so no use to introduce a line counter.

Comment: The code is a pseudocode example - as an idea to use which I stated at the bottom. I expect the OP to be reasonably competent to modify the idea to suit. eg `for ( int LineNo = 1; (txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null ; LineNo++)` or `if ((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null) break;` would both be solutions which do not need to read the entire file. Alternatively initialising & incrementing line number can be done with a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` keyword will jump to the next iteration of your loop.

```
while ((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (txtline == heading) continue; //Ignore headers

   //do standard processing
}
```

This code assumes you have the same headers in both files, if not, replace `heading` with the headers of the file you are reading from.

Comment: Why would you do that like this? OP specifically mentions the first line is the header line. Now if someone changes a header column name, you have to recompile your program. This adds unnecessary complexity. No need comparing it to a string. It's just the first line OP wants to skip.

Comment: He said he wants to skip the headers, not necessarily skip the first line.  If there were no headers written to the file, this would still function, whereas skipping the first line would lose a row. And generally I would expect the format of headers to be something pre-determined and not subject to change, but the format is easy to externalise to a config file.  I've also seen occasional CSV files with headers written every X lines.  Just illustrating a concept for the OP anyway, whatever works is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the answers are all valid, I would use a library *every time* for parsing CSV files.

Not only does it provide things out of the box to skip header rows, but it will also deal with pesky things like commas inside double quotes, etc.

[CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is my go-to CSV parsing library.

It also gives you really nice syntax, like this, quoted from the above link:

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();
```

Much easier to read ;)